# Include packages in R - Rserve - Java

Tags: java, r, package, libraries, rserve

I've been struggling with this issue for some days already, can't find the way to solve it.

I have an R script that works fine, and I want to access it from Java, but when I source the R script it fails to include packages in R and it doesn't recognise the functions inside. Why is this happenning? If any of you have an idea about why is this happening I would appreciate it.

This is the java code I use to call R...

```
public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {

System.out.println("result="+StartRserve.checkLocalRserve());

RConnection c = null;

try {
/* Create a connection to Rserve instance running on default port
* 6311
*/  

  c = new RConnection();

  c.eval("source(\"C:/mypath/myFunction\")");

  RList result = c.eval("myFunction("+args+")").asList();

  ... more code that fails to execute ....

  String processName = "Rserve.exe";

  if (isProcessRunning(processName)) {
    killProcess(processName);
  }

  c.close();


  }//Fin del Try
  catch (RserveException e) {
  String processName = "Rserve.exe";
  if (isProcessRunning(processName)) {
     killProcess(processName);
  }
  e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();   
  }
  }
  }
```

And here it is the R script that I call from JAVA...

```
myFunction=function(args){

    require('ROracle')
    require('DBI')
    require('janitor')

    source("mypath/functions.R")
    source("mypath/queries.R")

    aa <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3)
    bb <- tabyl(aa)

    ..... More code comes here but it Fails already ...

}
```

> [R ERROR]: Error in tabyl(aa) : could not find function "tabyl"

tabyl functions comes from library('janitor'), but it basically fails to import any of the libraries.

Why are the libraries not being imported?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is tabyl supposed to come from?

Comment: It comes from the janitor package, but anyway... It fails there because is the first functions that is referenced... If I remove that it will say that "could not find function "dbDriver"" which is coming from ROracle library... In the end it is failing to import all of them...

Comment: What happens if your try `bb <- janitor::tabyl(aa)` in the code? This should work even if package is not loaded.

Comment: `[R ERROR]: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'dplyr`

I get this... I feel like there's a problem with the libPaths(), but not sure how can i solve it

Comment: Okay I finally figured out what was going on... I will post an answer in case it may help someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to source a file that was in an user account from the server, so I didn't have enough privileges to read the libraries inside. I reinstalled R and saved all the files in the server, now everything works fine. I hope this may help someone else.